# What would be a good method for testing over 100,000 cases in Jest?

Tags: javascript, arrays, memory, jestjs

I use a cartesian combination method to generate combos of test cases from an array.

`const cartesian = (...a) => a.reduce((a, b) => a.flatMap(d => b.map(e => [d, e].flat())));`

Found in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303989/cartesian-product-of-multiple-arrays-in-javascript).

```js
let arrayOne = [0, 1];
let arrayTwo = [0, 1];

const result = cartesian(arrayOne, arrayTwo)

console.log(result)

/**
* Result should equal:
* [
* [0, 1],
* [1, 0],
* [1, 1],
* [0, 0] 
* ]
*/
```

That part is working nicely.

I then take the array of arrays generated from this method and pass them to Jest's `.each` method on the test.

```js
describe('test', () => {
  test.each(cases)('when one equals %s and two equals %s', (one, two) => {
    // my test logic
  })
})
```

This also works nicely. However, when I have a very large number of combinations I want to test,

`e.g., [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 ...]`

that's when things get tricky.

I don't think JavaScript is built to handle that level of computational complexity. I usually get a `heap out of memory` when I run through so many cases in a single test.

This is a shame, because this method is quite convenient for automating test case building, and I really would like to expand it to other languages (like PHP and Python), but I think I'll have the same problem once my test cases pass the 100,000 mark.

One method I've tried is limiting the number of test cases to an arbitrary number.

```
describe('test', () => {
  test.each(cases.slice(0,5000))('when one equals %s and two equals %s', (one, two) => {
    // my test logic
  })
})
```

This lets me run them without a problem, but I can't see all the cases without manually commenting out values in the arrays I've already tested.

```js
const arrayOne = [
  // 0
  1
  ...
]
```

Doing that every time doesn't seem right.

Is there some way of making the test:

1. Go through 50,000 records
2. Save their results
3. Clear the memory
4. Start again from the latest index

I think that might be how it's done.

Comment: Find a reasonable subset of inputs and outputs. I don’t think you need to test every combination

Comment: @DanielA.White I suppose that's the standard.

Comment: Seems like you are brute forcing with Jest which is already a heavy test framework. What's your exact use case behind doing such operations?

Comment: @Fcmam5 I just discovered the possibility of looping repetitive tests. I was simply exploring the limits.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simple loop through the tests one by one?  The test is Typescript/JavaScript, so do your testing in a loop.

```
describe('test', () => {
    for await (const case of cases) { // Doing the await in case you need async
        test('should ...', () => {
           // my test logic
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are trying to run a large set of tests derived from a Cartesian product. Assuming `cases` consists of the cases built by the Cartesian product, you can do:

```
describe('test', () => {
  for (const [one, two] of cases) {
    test(`when one equals ${one} and two equals ${two}`, () => {
      // my test logic
    })
  }
})
```

Or, even more directly, you can skip creating `cases`:

```
describe('test', () => {
  for (const one of arrayOne) {
    for (const two of arrayTwo) {
      test(`when one equals ${one} and two equals ${two}`, () => {
        // my test logic
      })
    }
  }
})
```